# How can I append text to the bottom of my MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, messageui

I would like to add the text "Sent from " to the bottom of the message

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
       MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
       controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
       [controller setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"A message from: %@",self.profileName]];
       [controller setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.cellBody] isHTML:NO];
       [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
       [controller release];
      }
      else {
       UIAlertView *alertView;
       alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"E-Mail Not Enabled" message:@"E-Mail is not supported on this device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alertView show];
       [alertView release];
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the message body as `isHTML:YES` and use line breaks `<br>` or try using `\n` in the `setMessageBody` string

Then just add your "sent from" message after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code I have changed the code as per your requirement

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
       MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
       controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
       [controller setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"A message from: %@",self.profileName]];
       [controller setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nSent from : %@",self.cellBody,self.profileName] isHTML:NO];
       [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
       [controller release];
      }
      else {
       UIAlertView *alertView;
       alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"E-Mail Not Enabled" message:@"E-Mail is not supported on this device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alertView show];
       [alertView release];
      }
```

Happy Coding...